# New construct 2.9 syntax for struct staticfield data type

Tags: python, python-2.7, construct

I had this, using construct 2.5.2:

```
something=Struct("somename",
Bytes("version",4),
StaticField("somefieldname",32)
)

myVar=something.parse('John')
myVar.version=struct.pack('<I',1)
myVar.somefieldname=struct.pack('<qqqq',0,0,0,0)
```

Now I have to change it in order to satisfy the new construct 2.9 syntax:

```
something="somename" / Struct (
"version" / Bytes(4)
"somefieldname" / ????
)
```

What is the old "StaticField" I used in order to store the struct.pack result called in the new construct version?

Comment: thanks for the edit, now I now style to use for the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

`StaticField` class is not available anymore in v. 2.9. 
Here is your example using `construct 2.9` syntax:

```
from construct import Int, Struct, GreedyString

# create struct
my_struct = Struct(
    "version" / Int,
    "somefieldname"/ GreedyString(encoding='utf-8')
)

# build an object in memory (a bytes object).
build = my_struct.build(dict(version=1, somefieldname="John"))

assert build == b'\x00\x00\x00\x01John'

# parse an in-memory buffer
parsed_data = my_struct.parse(build)

assert parsed_data.version == 1
assert parsed_data.somefieldname == "John"
```

[Construct docs](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html) has plenty of examples describing how to use different data types.